# Discord js sending a specific word from a list of random words

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
let replies = ["apple", "aerospace", "smart",  "telivision"]
let result = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies.length));

let wordembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(replies[result])
.setColor("3788E0")

message.channel.send(wordembed);
```

The code sends a random word everytime I use !word.

But how can I make it so that when I do !word 1 it should send apple and when I do !word 3 it should send smart

Comment: What do you mean by `when I do !word 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check for a first argument, and set the word as 1 subtracted from the first argument (indexes begin at 0).

```
// User input (arguments)
let args = message.content.substring(1).split(/ +/g);

let replies = ["apple", "aerospace", "smart",  "telivision"];
let result = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies.length));

if (args[1]) result = parseInt(args[1]) - 1;

let wordembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(replies[result])
.setColor("3788E0");

message.channel.send(wordembed);
```